# How to pass object to another screen via window.open

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following problem: I can't pass values to get to the other screen.
I have the following code that should pass an object to be received on the destination screen and I also don't know how to receive it on the destination

I want object = {a:121, b: 232} to be sent to the other screen

```
function openInNewTab(url: string | URL | undefined) {
    const params = `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=300,height=300`;
    var win = window.open(url,'_blank', params)!;
    win.focus();
  } 

<button id='btn' onClick={() =>  openInNewTab("../printer")}>abrir</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to query params, but is a not most best idea.

```js
window.open(`${url}?obj=${JSON.stringify(yourObject)}`)
```

But better, I can advise you to use some router library, for ex.
[react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

Comment: Hello friend, and how do I get on the other side, in the child component, this url value?